# Unity5. When I click on a UI button the GameObject behind it gets clicked

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06qKC.jpg. (screenshot of my game)

When I click on the Upgrade or Sell button the turret behind 
it gets "enabled". How can I change that ?  (It's a mobile game with touch input). Is there any code I should implement oder can I simply change that in the inspector?Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: You need to change the way you detect touch/click on the 3D object. Use the `EventSystems`. See "6.For 3D Object (Mesh Renderer/any 3D Collider)" from the answer in the duplicated question. You can also use `EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject` but that's  only a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking by using this first..

```
public static bool IsPointerOverUIObject() {
    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
    return results.Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean in the script of the UI button ? Btw thanks for your fast answer

Comment: I should have elaborated. Use it on GameObjects that may be "behind" UI elements to check if they should be clicked.

Comment: Strangely this worked for me :)
Thank you mr. Brookes, your beer is waiting for you 

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Raycast Trigger on the UI Image, it should block the raycasts and mouse click too.
Here is [documentation reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty new to c# could you describe what you mean with Raycast trigger ?

Comment: In Unity on your Button UI object there should be Raycast Trigger check box on its Image component.